# Is $F=\{f\in C^1([0,1]):~ |f(x)|\leq 1 ~\text{and}~ 1\leq f'(x)\leq 2 ~\text{for all }x\in [0,1]\}$ compact?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Inspired by the old [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507465/f-f-in-c10-1-hspace2mm-f-leq-m-f-leq-n-showing-it-is) I considered the following

Let $$F=\{f\in C^1([0,1]):~~ |f(x)|\leq 1 ~~\text{and}~~ 1\leq f'(x)\leq 2 ~~\text{for all }x\in [0,1]\}$$
the set of continuous, bounded by $-1$ and $1$, functions $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ with bounded, by $1$ and $2$, continuous first derivative.

In this case I can not apply the trick, which is applied there, and I guess $F$ is compact in this case, but I can not prove it yet.

> Is my guess right or rather $F$ is only pre-compact (subset closure of which is compact)?

**Theorem**(Arzela-Ascoli):

Let $X$ be a compact metric space, $(Y,d)$ any
metric space and $F$ a subset of $C(X,Y)$. Then $\operatorname{cl}(F)$ is compact iff the following two conditions are valid:

- $F$ is equicontinuous
- for each $x\in X$, the subset $F_x=\operatorname{cl}\left(\{f(x):~f\in F\}\right)$ is a compact subspace of $Y$.

where  $\operatorname{cl}(A)$ is a closure of $A$.

> Is $F$ closed subset of $C([0,1])$?

If $F$ is closed one can apply Arzela-Ascoli theorem to show that $F$ is compact, since boundedness of $F_x$ and equicontinuity of $F$ are clear in this case.

**Lemma**: If $F$ is an equicontinuous subspace of $C(X,Y)$ then so is $\operatorname{cl}(F)$.

By this lemma $F_x=\operatorname{cl}\left(\{f(x):~ f\in F\}\right)=\operatorname{cl}\left(\{f(x):~ f\in \operatorname{cl}(F)\}\right)$, am I right?

Comment: why is $F_x$ included in $[0,1]$?

Comment: Oh mistype, changed.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:
It is possible to show that
$$
 F_x = [x-1,x]
$$
explicitly.
To gain intuition of this fact it might help to think about what functions are in $F$ what and functions are not in $F$.